# Как сделать форму внутри формы или как поместить контент модального окна отдельно от кнопки

Tags: php, yii2

Есть одна большая форма редактирования конкурса, в конкурс можно прикрепить файлы, файлы грузятся еще одной формой, эта форма находится внутри родительской формы на модальном окне. Но т.к. форма внутри формы к моему огромному сожалению не может быть, то наверное вариант только сделать кнопку модального окна отдельно от его контента если это возможно. Но как я не знаю...

```
<? $contestForm = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
    <!-- тут что-то есть -->
    <? Modal::begin([
        'header' => Html::tag('h2', 'Добавление файла'),
        'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'Прикрепить файл', 'class' => 'btn btn-success'],
    ]) ?>
        <? $fileUploadForm = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
            <!-- тут что-то есть -->
        <? ActiveForm::end() ?>
    <? Modal::end() ?>
    <!-- тут что-то есть -->
<? ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

P.S. Я не могу просто вынести весь этот код модального окна вместе с формой из родительской формы потому что она нужна мне именно в этом месте (визуально).

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, правильно ли использовать одну форму внутри другой, но решение есть.

```
<?php 
$fileUploadForm = ActiveForm::begin(['upload-form']);
ob_start();
// Формируем input
echo $fileUploadForm->field($uploadModel, 'file')->file(['form' => 'upload-form']);
$uploadField = ob_get_clean();
ActiveForm::end();

$contestForm = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
    <!-- тут что-то есть -->
    <? Modal::begin([
        'header' => Html::tag('h2', 'Добавление файла'),
        'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'Прикрепить файл', 'class' => 'btn btn-success'],
    ]) ?>
        <?= $uploadField // Тут выведется поле из upload формы?>
            <!-- тут что-то есть -->

    <? Modal::end() ?>
    <!-- тут что-то есть -->
<? ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Я столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами такого подхода в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757144/yii2-activeform-ajax-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-submit-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B/757162)